# $\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} \cdot \frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\right)^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

why is this true?

$\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} \cdot \frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\right)^2$

My problem states that $\vec{F}$ is a conservative field, ie: $F = \nabla \phi$ for some scalar potential $\phi$. 
$$\begin{align}\vec{F}&=m\vec{a}\\
&=m\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t^2}
\end{align}$$

I now take the dot product of each side:

$$\vec{F} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t}= m\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Now, the textbook says that:

$$m\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}^2\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = \frac{m}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2$$

**How did the textbook get this answer?**: $\frac{m}{2} \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\right)^2$ ?

All of this leads to the result, which I'm OK with:

$$\int \limits_{A}^{B} \vec{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{r} = \bigg[\frac{m}{2}v^2\bigg]^{B}_{A}$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Chain Rule? This is an application of that rule

Comment: I don't see how chain rule applies... the derivative operator of the first term is already attached to $\vec{r}$, ie: $\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$... it can't be used to take the derivative of the second term: $\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}$ because it already busy taking the derivative of the first term.  if you could throw away the $\vec{r}$ and have  $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}$..then chain rule works...but that changes the equation?

Comment: $\frac{d^2 r_j}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{dt}r_j$  but $\frac{d^2 r_j}{dt^2} \ne (\frac{dr_j}{dt})^2$

Comment: anyway, $\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$ is a function with respect to t, say $\vec{g}(t)$. According to the chain rule, $\frac{d{\vec{g}}^2}{dt}=2*\vec{g}(t)*\frac{d\vec{g}}{dt}$

Answer (score 3):

You can see it more easily by expanding the product.
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}^2\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t^2} & 
= \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\mathrm{d}r_j}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2r_j}{\mathrm{d}t^2} 
= \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}r_j}{\mathrm{d}t} \right)^2 \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\mathrm{d}r_j}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}r_j}{\mathrm{d}t} 
= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t} \right) 
= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t} \right)^2
\end{aligned}

Comment: looks right,  but could you elaborate on this step: $\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{dr_j}{dt} \frac{d^2r_j}{dt^2}= \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{dr_j}{dt} \right)^2$  how did you do this part.  i'm a little bit confused how you change it like that... is this in a table somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: It's the chain rule, but somehow used backwards. Using the chain rule to take the derivative of an expression of the form $f\big(g(t)\big)$ with respect to $t$, we find $f'\big(g(t)\big) g'(t)$. Here, $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}r_j}{\mathrm{d}t}$, so we find that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}r_j}{\mathrm{d}t} \right)^2 = 2 \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}r_j}{\mathrm{d}t} \right) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}r_j}{\mathrm{d}t} = 2 \frac{\mathrm{d}r_j}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2r_j}{\mathrm{d}t^2}$.

Comment: is it something like this: $\frac{dr_j}{dt}\frac{d^2r_j}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d}{dt} r_j r_j = \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt} \frac{d}{dt} r_j r_j) = \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dr_j}{dt})^2$  ... I feel a little bit queasy about it though...because how can you push r_j to the other side of derivative...

Comment: wow... that blows my mind... ok.. thanks.