# $(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})\cdot(\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

prove the following is true:

$(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})\bullet(\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})^2$

where:

$\bullet \equiv \text{dot product}$

$\vec{r} \equiv x\hat{\text{i}} + y\hat{\text{j}} + z\hat{\text{k}}$

I tried applying chain rule on right hand side.  This gave me:

$(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})\bullet(\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})) = \frac{1}{2} 2(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})$

$(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})\bullet(\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})) = (\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r})$

not sure how I can add the dot product back in to the right hand side to get them to be equal...

also, is there a way to prove this by transforming  the left-hand side instead of the right-hand side?

because its backwards for the exercise that I took this math snippet from to guess backwards from the answer of the problem...

Comment: What's the difference between this and [your other question from earlier today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466327/fracd-vecrdt-cdot-fracd2-vecrdt2-frac12-fracddt-le)?

Comment: I would merge them together, I just don't have that admin power...

Comment: You can always edit your own earlier question. (A bit late now maybe, since you got several answers already, but it might be good to know for another time.)

Answer (score 1):

Just put
$$
{\bf v} = \frac{d{\bf r}}{dt}.
$$
Then, your identity becomes
$$
{\bf v}\cdot\frac{d{\bf v}}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}{\bf v}^2=
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}({\bf v}\cdot{\bf v})
$$
that you will recognize as the standard derivative of powers like $x^2/2$ with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

This is from a standard table of derivatives in vector calculus:

$\vec{v}\cdot \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}v^2$

Subsitute $\vec{v} = \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$ into this eqation:

$\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} \bullet \frac{d^2 \vec{r}}{dt^2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt})^2$

---

We can prove the derivative table entry as follows:

$\frac{d\vec{v}^2}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v})$

$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{v}^2 = \frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v})\cdot \vec{v} + \vec{v}\cdot \frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v})$

$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{v}^2 = \vec{v} \cdot \frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v})  + \vec{v}\cdot \frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v})$

$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{v}^2 = 2(\vec{v} \cdot \frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v}))$

$\boxed{\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\vec{v}^2 = \vec{v} \cdot \frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v})}$

Answer (score 0):

Your manipulation is essentially correct. The thing to remember is that if we have a vector $\vec{v}$, then the notation $\vec{v}^2$ means $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}$. Thus, for example we actually have
$\frac{d}{dt} (\vec{r}^2 )= 2 \vec{r} \cdot \frac{d}{dt} \vec{r}$.
Do you see how this tells fixes your issue?